# Replacing Grout Around Kitchen Sink

Tags: grout, kitchen-sink, caulking

first time poster, hope someone can help.  The grout around my kitchen sink is old and broken, and I'd like to replace it.  Not sure if it would be better with grout or caulk (I've never used grout, but I have some experience applying silicone caulk).  I live in a rental, so I don't want to go crazy, but it's worth a couple bucks and a few hours of my time to make it look better.  Any advice on the best material to use, any tools I might need or good videos / guides would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Current]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell if the material between the tile and sink is cement or backing board.  Anyway,

1. If that corner tile or any other one is loose and can be removed without breaking it, do so.
2. Use a dremel to remove exposed tile cement from removed tiles and all  the visible edge cement, to about a quarter inch deep.  You're creating a gap that you will replace with new material.
3. Also with a dremel remove the grout lines between the edge tiles.  Looks like the ones between the edge and regular tiles are ok.  Look at youtube tutorials on how to do this.
4. Use tile cement to replace tiles that were removed.  Force a little construction adhesive into the gap you made at the edge of the sound tiles.
5. Regrout the lines between the tiles.  NOT the sink edge.
6. Use silicone caulk at the interface between the tiles and sink.

Comment: Yeah, you should use caulk between the edge tiles and the sink, instead of grout.